# How to use pep8speaks to check the code style/structure of my project

Tags: python, continuous-integration, code-structure, pycodestyle

Reading the instructions here:
https://pep8speaks.com/

and here: 
https://github.com/OrkoHunter/pep8speaks?installation_id=6398017&setup_action=update#configuration

I am a bit confused on how to use pep8speaks to check the code style/structure of my project.

Anyone have a rough step-by-step guide on how to use pep8speaks. Many thanks.

Edit: Screenshot of a Pull Request from my project
[image: pep8speaks]

Edit no. 2: Screenshot of Fork "tab"
[image: pep8speaks2]

Comment: Can you be more specific? Which part are you struggling with, exactly?

Comment: Following the instructions, I have included a .pep8speaks.yml file in [my project in Github](https://github.com/leockl/helstrom-quantum-centroid-classifier). I don't understand how does pep8speaks checks my code from a Pull Request. Do I submit a Pull Request within my project or a Pull Request within this [link](https://github.com/OrkoHunter/pep8speaks?installation_id=6398017&setup_action=update#configuration). Once I submit a Pull Request, do I just "chat" with pep8speaks to check my codes, ie. like a chatbot within the Pull Request. An example to show how this works would be clearer.

Comment: https://pep8speaks.com/ mentions _A single comment on Pull Requests. No hustle on emails for new commits_. The [link](https://github.com/OrkoHunter/pep8speaks?installation_id=6398017&setup_action=update#configuration) you shared shows the same thing in a gif.

Comment: _Do I submit a Pull Request within my project or a Pull Request within this link._ That's a link to the pep8speaks GitHub repo, you don't want to be submitting a pull request there for your own project. _Once I submit a Pull Request, do I just "chat" with pep8speaks to check my codes, ie. like a chatbot within the Pull Request._ As I mentioned above, that's covered in two different areas. _An example to show how this works would be clearer._ https://github.com/OrkoHunter/pep8speaks?installation_id=6398017&setup_action=update#example.

Comment: Thanks. With the example in the gif, it would be clearer if each screenshot of what is happening is posted one after another, rather than in a gif where the images are changing and it's hard to tell which image starts first.

Comment: When I try to submit a Pull Request from my project, because I have forked my project from scikit-learn's project template, will I be submitting a Pull Request from my project to scikit-learn's project template? (I have attached a screenshot showing this in my original question above). How do I submit a Pull Request to "activate" pep8speaks? Many thanks for having a look at this

Comment: _When I try to submit a Pull Request from my project, because I have forked my project from scikit-learn's project template, will I be submitting a Pull Request from my project to scikit-learn's project template?_ I believe so, yes.

Comment: _How do I submit a Pull Request to "activate" pep8speaks?_ Now I'm not entirely sure, I'm nowhere near an expert with Git/GitHub, but you should be able to fork your own project (which would make it a fork of a fork), and then submit a pull request to yourself. May I ask why you're trying to use this? Are you just looking for a way to have your code checked automatically on GitHub?

Comment: If I am the owner of a project, I don't think I can fork my own project, as shown in another screenshot that I have attached to my original question above - the Fork "tab" is blank out and when I point my cursor to the Fork "tab", the message in the black strip comes up. I am using pep8speaks because it is one of the requirements for Continuous Integration if you want your package to be included in the scikit-learn-cont library. See point 4 [here](https://sklearn-template.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quick_start.html)

Comment: Just an update, I have contacted the pep8speaks developer about my questions and managed to resolved it now. Many thanks for looking at this again!

Comment: You should post an answer explaining everything!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure! Once you have installed and configure pep8speaks in your project, just submit a Pull Request (say with comment “Trigger pep8speaks“ and pep8speaks will reply back like a chat bot with all the checks. It will even send you an email of all the checks. In my case where my project was forked from another project, when the Pull Request is submitted from my project (to the other project), pep8speaks will do the check on just my project. Once you have the checks, you can then close the Pull Request which is sitting on the other project.